# c - seeing random numbers in my loop after the array length has been reached?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I am just creating a simple array in C and outputting the result to a console to see what the content of the array is.

I am using the code below and that is everything that is the whole program for this test.

It asks what size array I want, so I put in 6 for example, and then I put in 6 numbers.

Now when I declare the array at the start I set that the maximum numbers can be 10, so I thought that it meant that I can add up to 10 numbers in the array.

But when I put in 6 numbers and then do a loop to see what is in the array I get this:

5

1

2

4

3

6

4203737

0

4225576

0

---

Process exited after 7.421 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

The numbers I am asking about are from the 420 and then 0 etc.
**Why are they there**

They make up the total index to 10, but I only want 6 or whatever number I set to be the index length?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int array[10];
int position, c, n, value;

printf("Enter number of elements in array\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter %d elements\n", n);

for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
  scanf("%d", &array[c]);

//Printing the array so we know what is in it 
int i = 0;
int sizeOfArray = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); //Determine the length of the array
for(i; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {

    printf("%d\n", array[i]);

} 

return 0;
}
```

Thank you for you help on this one, it is probably an easy one - always seems to be ;-)

Comment: Your array is uninitialized, hence you get random numbers at non-assigned elements. Try `int array[10] = { 0 };` and spot the difference.

Comment: I wouldn't use `int sizeOfArray = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);`. You've already used `10` explicitly earlier, use it here as well. Or better, `#define MAXELS 10` somewhere at the top and use that both times.

Comment: @Evert Thank you for the note about the sizeof - it makes sense and I was just mixing up something else :-) +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you declared the array to be length 10, it will always be an array of length 10 (`sizeof` will return `10*sizeof(array[0])`), no matter many data points you have manually set. When you initialize an array that's not `static` or global, there's no guarantee what the data will be if you don't explicitly set the data yourself. It's undefined behavior.

In this case, the data happens to be 0s and 4203737s because of your compiler's implementation of the language.

In order to only print the elements that you have set, do the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int array[10];
    int position, c, n, value;

    printf("Enter number of elements in array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter %d elements\n", n);

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
      scanf("%d", &array[c]);

    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < n; i++) {

        printf("%d\n", array[i]);

    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Super :-) Thank you for the working example. I will look into initializing a bit more.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `initialize an array that's not static or global`; I always forget in which cases C provides a default 0 initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int array[10];
```

allocates storage for the array, but does not initialise it, so the array contains whatever happens to be kept in memory at that time.

To initialise the array to zero you can do

```
int array[10] = { 0 };
```

or alternatively

```
int array[10];
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: Ok I have done that, but now when I type 6 for the length, I get 4 (four) zero's after the last number - can I remove those?

Comment: In the for loop, do `for(i; i < n; i++)` instead of `for(i; i < sizeOfArray; i++)`